# Symfony3: Apply function to the output of every Twig render

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.2

In my Twig templates I often have assignments at the top, such as:

`{{ set something = value() }}`

Due to that, there often are a few blank lines before my opening `<html>` tag. To fix that I'd like to run `trim()` on the output of every Twig render, be it 
`$this->renderView()` or `$this->render()`.

I could do it "manually", but I was wondering if there's a way to have Symfony do it automatically, maybe extending Twig or adding an event listener. Is it possible to do so? I'm using Symfony 3.2.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not very clear and a lot of people will downvote it unless you update the question. What are you trying to achieve? Clearly you want to remove whitespace, but why? What problem are you trying to solve? Do you have some example code?

Comment: I thought it was a pretty straightforward question... I have updated it now with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using white space per tag (prepending or appending a '-' to a tag as in *{{- xyz}})* or *{{- xyz -}})* to trim both sides which works for

- {{ … }}
- {% … %}
- {# … #}

and complete deletion of whitespace via *{% spaceless %}...{% spaceless %}* I doubt there's any easy way to delete white space as specific as you would want it to do.

Further read: https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#whitespace-control

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your base twig template with [spaceless](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/spaceless.html) tag to avoid spaced before html tag.

Comment: The _spaceless_ tag doesn't just trim spaces before html tag, it trims all spaces so your output looks like _'<html><body><div>asdf</div></body></html>'_ without any line breaks. One could try to place it around the assignments done before the first actual HTML tag however.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this will work. In your base template `base.html.twig' add this on the top (before  tag):

```
{%- block variables -%}{%- endblock -%}
```

Then in your extended file call:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{%- block variables -%}
   {{ set something = value() }}
{%- endblock -%}
```

Or something like that. It might work?